# Rotate images without saving the whole image in memory

Tags: java, image, image-processing, png, bufferedimage

I'm saving a large PNG file (40000 x 3000) using [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pngj/) library. Now I need to rotate the image 90 degrees to the right without saving the whole image in memory. PNGJ library is limited to write images line by line, so I can't rotate each line and write the imagem column by column.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PNGJ library is limited to write images line by line

Actually, it's the PNG format that's line-oriented. And you can't read a single pixel of a PNG image without reading all the "previous" pixels. So, I guess you are out of luck.

The best you can do, I think, if you cannot store the full image in memory, is to load and write it by `K` horizontal stripes. You fill the first stripe by reading the full image (you only store the fist pixels of each row, that correspond to the pixels of the first horizontal stripe of the rotated image, discarding the rest), write it, and read again the file to fill and write the second stripe, etc.
This involves `K` readings of the original file (of course, you should make the stripe as thick as your memory permits, so as to make `K` small). I hope you get the idea.

You can do that with PNGJ.

Comment: Do you know a better way to do it in a different format?

Comment: Well, with a non-compressed format (say, BMP) you could read randomly the pixels (RandomAccessFile). I doubt that this would be a better way, though, than what I proposed above.